# How to have Hashem listen to/respond to your tefillos

Tags: tefilla, shidduchim-dating

I've spent years davening incessantly for a shidduch, and recently I've tried to be more consistent about being kovea ittim, but unfortunately none of it seems to have any impact at all. Are there sources that talk about how you can "motivate" (so to speak) Hashem to listen to your tefillos?

Comment: Presumably He already is listening and responding no[t yet].

Comment: I know, so is there anything you can actually do to change the response from "no" to "yes"? Or are we just powerless basically?

Comment: I think as hard as it is to accept - no tefilla is ever wasted, and pG, Hashem is accumulating all the resultant sechar (reward), to bless you with an extra special wife! Hatzlocho

Comment: Daven for others that are in need of Shidduchim. המתפלל בעד חבירו הוא נענה תחילה

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%91_%D7%91 מפני שדרכו של איש לחזר על אשה ואין דרכה של אשה לחזר על איש, משל לאדם שאבדה לו אבידה – מי חוזר על מי? בעל האבידה מחזר על אבידתו So assuming Hashem *is* listening to your *tefillos* then He is telling you that your *bashert* is somewhere else. So you have to go and find her.

Comment: Hi, could you translate that please?

Comment: You really should talk to a Rav to get an idea. There are a myriad of possible reasons why someone doesn't find a shidduch. It could be that it is just not the right time, or it could be something they did that needs fixing, or they need to daven more/better.

Comment: Draw a circle around yourself and tell God that you won't leave the circle until you get a shidduch.

Comment: I've recently met someone who told me he had been on a 100 dates and wasn't married yet. Problem was his list of criteria was all wrong. Not saying this is your case but, in addition to praying, speaking with experienced people in the field (a Rav, wise older friend) might help. Behatzlaha rabba and may we soon hear good news !

Comment: I don't have a rav, or any friends. Thanks for the idea though

Comment: It is really hard to succeed in shidduchim without someone you trust to turn to for advice. It seems like your first step should be to follow the advice of Pirkei Avos and get a Rav. (It is also worth davening to find the right one.) Hatzlacha Rabbah!

Comment: Wow, good question. I hope Hashem answers you soon.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [Adai Ad](https://adaiad.org/tefillah-is-not-about-changing-hashems-plans-its-about-changing-yourself/)

> **Tefillah is not that we are trying to change Hashem’s mind about our
> lives. It is more about changing ourselves. When we change ourselves,
> our lives change.**

This idea is well-known and accepted. Please read more on the site.

I agree with @N.T. I suggest you first daven that Hashem should open your heart to accept the idea of having a Rav with whom you can discuss your life. Then daven that you should locate this Rav. From then on it should be relatively easier.